# Share store between two components

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

How to share store between two components?

First component should use a full store, second component should use a filtered store.

If i filter store in second component, store also filtered in first component.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you will need to create a second copy of your store:

```
var newStore = new Ext.data.Store({});
newStore.loadData(oldStore.getRange());
// Do filter
```

Comment: I forgot all, stores should synchronize with each other.